# Why device pixel ratio change between web pages on same device and OS?

Tags: css, web, sass, responsive-design, devicepixelratio

I Would like to understand why device pixel ratio vary from web site and from different Os. For example on the same device [this site](http://elaisian.com) got different pixel ratio on Windows / Ubuntu.
On Windows the pixel ratio is 1.34 when on Ubuntu is 1. I would like to know what is the best way to approach this problem in order to have a consistent view on any device.

Answer (score 0):

Each OS will have the same resolution, whatever the Display's resolution is set at. you can go to settings and change the resolutions